# JQuery Mobile 1.4.5 radio control group breaks after back button is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile, radio-button

I've recently upgraded from JQM 1.4.2 to 1.4.5, but doing so has produced a new bug for me. I have a search option in a panel that is displayed on every page which has a radio control group:

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
    <input type="radio" name="choiceActiveCont" id="choiceActiveCont" value="choiceActiveCont" checked="checked">
     <label for="choiceActiveCont">Active Contracts</label>
     <input type="radio" name="choiceActiveCont" id="choiceAllCont" value="choiceAllCont">
     <label for="choiceAllCont">All Contracts</label>
</fieldset>
```

This has always worked fine. However if I navigate between pages, then press the back button this control group is totally broken:

[image: broken radio button control group image]

Does anyone have any ideas on what the problem could be here? Thanks

Comment: If the same code used to work without any issue on 1.4.2, then it is a bug in 1.4.5 that should be reported.

Comment: ok. do you know where I can report a bug?

Comment: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues Make sure to provide a full demo with all details.

Comment: thanks I've reported it... any ideas for a work around?

Comment: It's better to add fiddle that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Make sure that in each page you are using unique IDs for the inputs and corresponding label fors.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys, this is fixed now please see my answer below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed - the issue was with the IDs of the checkboxes. JQM have changed the way the label of a checkbox is identified when they fixed another bug. The new way of identifying a checkbox's label is consistent with the spec, but it also means that they search the entire document for the first label belonging to the given checkbox. So, they'll grab the first label, even if that label is on a different jQM page.

To fix this I avoided using IDs altogether. The checkboxradio widget will work without making use of IDs if the

> < input >

is a child of the

> < label >

So,

```
<label><input type="checkbox" name="something">Something</label>
```

will work, and does not need an ID.

*Answer thanks to JQM bug team! I hope this helps someone else with the same issue.

Comment: Why don't you use an external panel? since you're using the same panel for all pages. Less code.

Comment: Then the code shouldn't break, unless you have used same ID in panel and somewhere else ;)